# when i try to get the user name in c# i get this message <Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type>

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("what is your Name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run I get this message, Says: < Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type. [testdrive] csharp(CS8600) [Ln 9, Col 27] >.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on .NET 6 and have activated [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). Then  you have to declare `string name` as `string? name` since [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0) can return `null`. Documentation:

> The next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more
> lines are available.

Now by default all reference types are not nullable. If you want to make a variable or field nullable you have to tell the compiler so. So that warning is telling you that this method can return null, so you should take care of that. After declaring `name` as a nullable string, every method which is using that variable knows that it also has to take care of that.

Comment: I appreciate you a lot for your help, and I wanna say thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6, the return type for `Console.ReadLine` is `string?` but you're assigning it to a `string` variable, i.e. you're assigning a potentially `null` value to a non-nullable variable. While that method can theoretically return `null`, it never will in your average Console application, so you can safely tell the compiler that:

```cs
string name = Console.ReadLine()!;
```

That null forgiving operator tells the compiler that an expression that can theoretically be `null` will definitely not be at run time. It's sort of like casting in that it tells the compiler that only a specific possibility will ever actually occur at run time.

The alternative would be to declare your variable as being nullable or just let the type be inferred by using `var`. That could lead to similar issues down the track but it wouldn't in this case because where you use that variable will allow `null` anyway.

If you're going to target .NET 6 then you should either disable nullable reference types or learn about them and how to handle them properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help, so I'm gonna pick a time to learn about nullable.